# OData Client App Authentication with Azure App Service Example

Tags: odata, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

Is there an example of a external OData client using AAD to access an Azure App Service acting as a OData server? The identity being provided is of the client app itself registered as a native app in AAD, not the user, so no user authentication interface is needed in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's same as regular Web API to set up AD for Odata service. So you can refer to this sample: https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon

The minor difference is on client side. As the client code is generated by "Odata Client Code Generator", it is not using HTTP Client class. You need to leverage [DataServiceContext.SendingRequest Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.sendingrequest?view=netframework-4.7.2) to add authorization header.

Refer to the code below:

```
private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppKey"];
    private static string OdataServiceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OdataTestId"];

    static string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

    private static AuthenticationContext authContext = null;
    private static ClientCredential clientCredential = null;
    // Get an entire entity set.
    static void ListAllProducts(Default.Container container)
    {
        foreach (var p in container.Products)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", p.Name, p.Price, p.Category);
        }
    }

    static void AddProduct(Default.Container container, OdataTest.Models.Product product)
    {

        container.SendingRequest2 += Container_SendingRequest2;
        container.AddToProducts(product);
        var serviceResponse = container.SaveChanges();
        foreach (var operationResponse in serviceResponse)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", operationResponse.StatusCode);
        }
    }

    private static void Container_SendingRequest2(object sender, Microsoft.OData.Client.SendingRequest2EventArgs e)
    {
        AuthenticationResult result= authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(OdataServiceId, clientCredential).Result;
        e.RequestMessage.SetHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + result.AccessToken);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
        // TODO: Replace with your local URI.
        string serviceUri = "http://localhost:59837/";
        var container = new Default.Container(new Uri(serviceUri));

        var product = new OdataTest.Models.Product()
        {
            Name = "Yo-yo",
            Category = "Toys",
            Price = 4.95M
        };

        AddProduct(container, product);
        ListAllProducts(container);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```